# Maintaining several versions of a software in bzr

Tags: version-control, bazaar

I'm a single developer of a project. I have a central bazaar repo for the project code:

```
C:\Dev\MyProjRepo>bzr info
Shared repository (format: 2a)
Location:
  shared repository: .
```

The repo contains a trunk directory

```
C:\Dev\MyProjRepo>cd trunk

C:\Dev\MyProjRepo\trunk>bzr info
Repository tree (format: 2a)
Location:
  shared repository: C:\Dev\MyProjRepo
  repository branch: .

Related branches:
  submit branch: .
```

Now, I have stopped developing version 1 (created appropriate tags on each release) and continue developing verion 2. This development is performed in the trunk. In parallel I need to maintain version 1. I'm a former SVN user, so I create a directory "branches/version1", branch the appropriate revision from the trunk into that directory and then checkout/branch from this new location ad libidum with occasional merges between the trunk and the version 1 branch. Is this how the the things are done in bzr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar, but not quite. You're already setup with a shared repository, so switch to that directory and then use the `bzr branch` command:

```
C:\Dev\MyProjRepo>bzr branch -rtag:version1tag trunk version1
```

Use whatever tag you used for version 1 in place of "version1tag". That will create a branch in `C:\Dev\MyProjectRepo\version1` that will be branched from the revision represented by that tag. Bear in mind that creating a branch doesn't actually create a new revision like SVN does.

A neat trick for visualizing your branches is to use `bzr qlog` in the shared repository directory. That will show you the history for all branches and it will connect them with lines to indicate their ancestry and merges.